# How to reuse a wtform for updating and adding records in the database

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

This is the form that I use for registering new projects and updating existing projects:

```
class ProjDataForm(FlaskForm):
    proj_key = StringField("Project Key", validators=[DataRequired()])
    ...
    def validate_proj_key(self, proj_key):
            raise ValidationError("That Project Key already exists.")
```

This is my model:

```
class ProjectData(db.Model):
    proj_key = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

I added a custom validation so I can have a unique "proj_key" for registering a new project.

what I did and still did not worked (I most likely made and error though):

```
#forms
class ProjDataForm(FlaskForm):
    ...
    new_proj = True
    if new_proj == True:
        def validate_proj_key(self, proj_key)
            raise ValidationError("That Project Key already exists.")

#routes
form = ProjDataForm()
form.new_proj = False
if form.new_proj == False and form.validate_on_submit():
    ...
```

I know that my design is not good, and I should redesign it, but Im just wondering if it is possible to ignore a custom validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new_pro` variable needs be a class instance variable. This will allow you to set its status when you create a `ProjDataForm` instance and will be accessible in the `validate_proj_key` method.

For example:

Override `ProjDataForm` `__init__` method, adding a parameter `is_new_project`, something like the following:

```
class ProjDataForm(FlaskForm):

    def __init__(self, is_new_project, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) for Python 3
        self.is_new_project = is_new_project
```

Now in your custom validator you can access the `is_new_project` instance variable:

```
class ProjDataForm(FlaskForm):

    def __init__(self, is_new_project, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) for Python 3
        self.is_new_project = is_new_project


    def validate_proj_key(self, proj_key)
        # Do we need to validate the project key? Check if the is_new_project instance variable is true
        if self.is_new_project:
            # Check if project_key exists or not
            # blah blah
            raise ValidationError("That Project Key already exists.")
```

In your routes construct the form with the appropriate `is_new_project` value:

```
@app.route('/new_project', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_project_route()

    form = ProjDataForm(is_new_project=True)

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # blah blah
        pass


@app.route('/edit_project', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_project_route()

    form = ProjDataForm(is_new_project=False)

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # blah blah
        pass
```